# PageSpeed is A, 91% but Fully Load Time is 4.8 Seconds

Tags: performance

As my title suggests there is, to me, a discrepancy with the A Rating I received.

My site using GMetrix ranks very high but the "Page Load" seems very slow.

Why isn't that bringing down my measurement?

I guess my question is - how accurate is Page Loading, and surely that's the biggest driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full page-load time is inclusive of asynchronous, deferred, and non-blocking resources (scripts, CSS, etc.). But most tools (rightly) consider metrics like first byte, first contentful paint, etc., more important. The reason is simple. From the user's perspective, he will see an interactive page much quicker compared to the full load time.